# Does homomorphic operations have to process one level by one level in BGV?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Suppose the highest level is $L$. There are 2 ciphertexts from 2 different messages under the same secret key but in different level, one is in level $\ell$: $\mathsf{ct}(\pmb{m})\in\mathcal{R}_{Q_{\ell}}^{2}$, one is in level $k$: $\mathsf{ct'}(\pmb{m}')\in\mathcal{R}_{Q_{k}}^{2}$, and $k<l-1$.

We want to calculate homomorphic multiplication of $\mathsf{ct}$ and $\mathsf{ct'}$. Should we move $\mathsf{ct}(\pmb{m})$ down, step by step, or can we actually move it just once by directly switching $Q_{\ell}$ to $Q_{k}$?

I have this confusion because I didn't find a scheme that seems to have discussed on this situation. Do we have papers/references discussing about it? Thanks!

Comment: They must be in the same level, and the library provides the tools for that...

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka. I mean should I move the ct up/down one level by another, or can I jump multiple levels for a ct?

Comment: Switching multiple down levels is possible, afaik for the up-level you need some other operation like bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka. I understand it now.